# Adding field from another table into exising functioning query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have 2 systems, the Warehouse management system (WMS) and SAP.

I have a query I can run in SAP which will generate me a TRUE free stock report for all items based on information in the WMS (A1WMS).

The query generate 2 columns, 'WH Free Stock' and PRODUCT

Each PRODUCT is also in our SAP database. I want to pull the product group assigned to these products into the report as a third column. How do I achieve this?

thanks

```
SELECT 

   CAST(TB2.QTY_UNALLOCATED as nvarchar) [WH Free Stock], TB2.PRODUCT
FROM 
 (SELECT T40.PRODUCT , SUM(T40.QUANTITY * T40.PACKSIZE) - SUM(ISNULL(T41.QTY_PICKLOC, 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(T42.QTY_REPLENIS, 0)) QTY_UNALLOCATED
                              FROM A1WMS.DBO.BINLOCAT T40 
                                    JOIN A1WMS.DBO.BINMSTR T47 ON T40.BINLABEL = T47.BINLABEL
                                    LEFT JOIN (SELECT T41.EXTENDED, T41.BINLABEL, T41.PACKSIZE, SUM((T41.QTY_TOPICK - T41.QTY_PICKED) / T41.PACKSIZE) QTY_PICKLOC
                                                      FROM A1WMS.DBO.PICKLOC T41 WHERE T41.PCKLOC_ST = '' AND T41.ALLOCATED = '1'
                                                      GROUP BY T41.EXTENDED, T41.BINLABEL, T41.PACKSIZE) T41 ON T40.EXTENDED = T41.EXTENDED AND T40.BINLABEL = T41.BINLABEL AND T40.PACKSIZE = T41.PACKSIZE
                                    LEFT JOIN (SELECT T42.EXTENDED, T42.BULKSLOT, T42.BULKPACK, SUM((T42.QTY_REQD * T42.PACKSIZE) / T42.BULKPACK) QTY_REPLENIS
                                                      FROM A1WMS.DBO.REPLENIS T42
                                                      GROUP BY T42.EXTENDED, T42.BULKSLOT, T42.BULKPACK) T42 ON T40.EXTENDED = T42.EXTENDED AND T40.BINLABEL = T42.BULKSLOT AND T40.PACKSIZE = T42.BULKPACK
                              WHERE (T40.QUANTITY > 0 OR T40.BINTYPE <> 'S') AND T40.RESERVED NOT IN ('B', 'I') AND
                              T40.BINLABEL NOT LIKE '#%' AND T47.RESERVED <> 'B' AND T40.BINLABEL NOT LIKE 'RECV%' AND
                              T40.BINLABEL NOT LIKE 'QUAR%' AND T40.BINLABEL NOT LIKE 'REP%' AND T40.BINLABEL NOT LIKE 'RET%' AND
                              T40.ZONE NOT IN ('Q','S','L','C','R')
                              GROUP BY T40.PRODUCT) TB2
```

[image: CURRENT OUTCOME / DESIRED OUTCOME]

Comment: "_How do I achieve this?_" By using a join, most likely. There isn't nearly enough information in your question to be more specific.

Comment: Those 2 databases, are they on the same or different server? If they are on the same server, you can do a cross database query, if not then create a linked server... You could do it through SSIS as well if you are familiar with it

Comment: The two databases on the same server. The WMS database name is A1WMS the SAP database is called NewLive. I am planning to run the query in the query manager in SAP Business One. The table in NewLive which holds the product id and product group is OITM

Comment: Are you using Sql Server or some other Database Management System?

Comment: We are using SQL server

Comment: LEFT JOIN to NewLive ON TB2.Product = NewLive.Product (via Cross database join), then add NewLive.ProductGroup to your select.

Answer (score 0):

Using the comment provided by MguerraTorres, here is the full select:

```
SELECT 
   CAST(TB2.QTY_UNALLOCATED as nvarchar) [WH Free Stock], TB2.PRODUCT, ISNULL(NewLive.ProductGroup,'NoProductGroupFound')
FROM 
 (SELECT T40.PRODUCT , SUM(T40.QUANTITY * T40.PACKSIZE) - SUM(ISNULL(T41.QTY_PICKLOC, 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(T42.QTY_REPLENIS, 0)) QTY_UNALLOCATED
                              FROM A1WMS.DBO.BINLOCAT T40 
                                    JOIN A1WMS.DBO.BINMSTR T47 ON T40.BINLABEL = T47.BINLABEL
                                    LEFT JOIN (SELECT T41.EXTENDED, T41.BINLABEL, T41.PACKSIZE, SUM((T41.QTY_TOPICK - T41.QTY_PICKED) / T41.PACKSIZE) QTY_PICKLOC
                                                      FROM A1WMS.DBO.PICKLOC T41 WHERE T41.PCKLOC_ST = '' AND T41.ALLOCATED = '1'
                                                      GROUP BY T41.EXTENDED, T41.BINLABEL, T41.PACKSIZE) T41 ON T40.EXTENDED = T41.EXTENDED AND T40.BINLABEL = T41.BINLABEL AND T40.PACKSIZE = T41.PACKSIZE
                                    LEFT JOIN (SELECT T42.EXTENDED, T42.BULKSLOT, T42.BULKPACK, SUM((T42.QTY_REQD * T42.PACKSIZE) / T42.BULKPACK) QTY_REPLENIS
                                                      FROM A1WMS.DBO.REPLENIS T42
                                                      GROUP BY T42.EXTENDED, T42.BULKSLOT, T42.BULKPACK) T42 ON T40.EXTENDED = T42.EXTENDED AND T40.BINLABEL = T42.BULKSLOT AND T40.PACKSIZE = T42.BULKPACK
                              WHERE (T40.QUANTITY > 0 OR T40.BINTYPE <> 'S') AND T40.RESERVED NOT IN ('B', 'I') AND
                              T40.BINLABEL NOT LIKE '#%' AND T47.RESERVED <> 'B' AND T40.BINLABEL NOT LIKE 'RECV%' AND
                              T40.BINLABEL NOT LIKE 'QUAR%' AND T40.BINLABEL NOT LIKE 'REP%' AND T40.BINLABEL NOT LIKE 'RET%' AND
                              T40.ZONE NOT IN ('Q','S','L','C','R')
                              GROUP BY T40.PRODUCT) TB2
LEFT JOIN NewLive.dbo.OITM NewLive on NewLive.Product = TB2.Product
```

The usage of a `LEFT JOIN` against NewLive.dbo.OITM ensures that you'll get all rows from TB2 even if no matching product can be found on OITM.  If a matching product can't be found on OITM, nulls will be returned for Newlive.ProductGroup.  You could then use `ISNULL` to provide a more meaningful description like 'NoProductGroupFound'  NewLive.ProductGroup was added to the top most `SELECT` statement.

This ALL assumes that the login that is running this query also has appropriate permissions in the NewLive database.

Comment: Hi Scott, how come there is no mention of the A1WMS database in the left join?

Comment: TB2 appears to have everything you need from A1WMS